# pgfgantt externally compiled

Tags: tikz-external, pgfgantt

I cannot get my gantt chart compiled when using \usepgfplotslibrary{external} and \tikzexternalize. (also use the compilation option -shell-escape when compiling) I just took the basic example from the documentation and it works when compiling traditionally. Here is a minimal example:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepackage{pgfgantt}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
  \tikzexternalize

  \begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
        \gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
        \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
        \ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
        \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
        \ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
        \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7} \ganttnewline
        \ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
        \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
        \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
    \end{ganttchart}
  \end{document}
```

I have some very large figures in my real document so I am afraid I really need "external".
Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out the answer is quite easy. In order to make use of the external functionality, I just need to put it explicitly in a tikzpicture environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
      \gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
      \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
      \ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
      \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
      \ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
      \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7} \ganttnewline
      \ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
      \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
      \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
  \end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now my question looks silly. My apologies.

Comment: Not silly, it helped me. Thanks!

Comment: But I just figured out that externalizing a ganttchart breaks the automatic setting of the width.

Comment: I don't have an issue with that (yet :-) ), could you post the sample code?

Comment: Just add `expand chart = \textwidth` as option to the chart, this won't work. Which makes sense, because it takes multiple runs to get the correct value for the width.